# Como iterar uma faixa de datas em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, loop, datetime

Quando queremos ir de um ponto a outro e faixa de dados podemos ir somando 1 se for algo numérico ou se tiver como enumerar pelo `IEnumerable`. Mas sem criar um *array* e colocar várias datas nele não tem como ir adicionando o valor numérico ou usar o padrão de enumeração. E mesmo para colocar essas datas no *array* teria que ir andando de uma em uma.

Então como ir, por exemplo do primeiro dia do mês ao último e usar isso de alguma forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem inúmeras maneiras de chegar no resultado, mas o mais simples é fazer justamente ir somando 1 no número e pegar o próximo, afinal a data é só um número. Essa é uma coisa que pode não parecer para muitas pessoas. Só que não tem um operador de adição, tem que fazer de outra forma.

Outra coisa que algumas pessoas não sabem que um `for` permite fazer o passo, que geralmente é um incremento de 1 número, mas pode colocar qualquer coisa ali.

Então da forma mais simples é só fazer um `for`:

```
var inicio = new DateTime(2023, 04, 01);
var fim = new DateTime(2023, 04, 30);
for (var dia = inicio; dia <= fim; dia = dia.AddDays(1)) Console.WriteLine(dia);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/npHb1x). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eTW2Tc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/IterateRange.cs).

Então o segredo é o [`AddDays()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e guardar um outro objeto com o novo valor por ser um objeto imutável. Lembrando que pode ir ao contrário se usar um valor negativo como argumento do método, não tem um específico para subtrair.

Se você usar o [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pode ser melhor ainda. Em alguns casos precisa ficar pegando o `Date` do `DateTime`.

É possível criar métodos de extensão para facilitar isto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

var inicio = new DateTime(2023, 04, 01);
var fim = new DateTime(2023, 04, 30);
foreach (var dia in GetDays(inicio, fim)) Console.WriteLine(dia);

static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDays(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    for (var day = start; day <= end; day = day.AddDays(1)) yield return day;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JKY0Yh). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HS9gmk). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DateRangeEnumarable.cs).

Ou pode fazer algo mais simples indicando a ação a ser executada:

```
using System;

var inicio = new DateTime(2023, 04, 01);
var fim = new DateTime(2023, 04, 30);
DoDays(inicio, fim, (DateTime dia) => Console.WriteLine(dia));

static void DoDays(DateTime start, DateTime end, Action<DateTime> action) {
    for (var day = start; day <= end; day = day.AddDays(1)) action(day);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uz06BS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hVGcZQ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DateRangeLambda.cs).

Comment: Pode configurar para ele adicionar por intervalos também passando uma variável com o intervalo para `AddDays(intervalo)`. Também seria legal se pudesse mostrar como criar um método de extensão para essa classe se tiver como.

Comment: Sem dúvida. Verei se criou algo mais.